# Why is scientific notation not identical to integer in php?

Tags: php, integer, identity, equality, scientific-notation

I just wondered why my if statement was not entered when using scientific notation, i.e. `1e2` instead of `100` and `1e6` instead of `1000000`.

It turns out, those are only equal and not identical, as seen by the following code:

```
<?php
echo "Integer: " . 100; // prints 100
echo "\n";
echo "Scientific notation: " . 1e2; // prints 100
echo "\n";

echo "Equality: ";

if(100 == 1e2) {
    echo "as expected";
} else {
    echo "wtf php";
}
// prints "Equality: as expected"


echo "\n";
echo "Identity: ";

if(100 === 1e2) {
    echo "as expected";
} else {
    echo "wtf php";
}
// prints "Identity: wtf php"
```

I have [run it on different php versions](https://3v4l.org/GdvHH#v430) and it seems to at least be consistent, as this behavior is the same across: 4.3.0 - 5.0.5, 5.1.1 - 5.6.27, hhvm-3.10.0 - 3.13.2, 7.0.0 - 7.1.0RC5.

Yet: Why!?

Comment: Because scientific notation is a floating type in php, not an integer type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the === checks for the same value and the same type. 1e2 is a double, 100 is an integer so they are not the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`===` operator, in php, consider the type of the operands.
`1e2` even return a `float` number, and `100` is an integer.
so, it's equals in values (`==`), but not in types (`===`).